# Getting errors in scss file like Expression expected.ts(1109)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, debugging, sass

I am getting errors in all scss file like these

1. Expression expected.ts(1109)
2. ',' expected.ts(1005)
3. Even for varaible declaration like these `$gray-100-dark: #1b1b29;` 
    `Cannot find name '$gray'`

Working on a react project where TS are used

Comment: It could be better if you share the relevant part of the code

Comment: I am just importing like this .@import 'init'; getting error at .@import 
i am using tsx for my react project and I have components with jsx as well but that imports are not related to jsx components like I have downloaded a code base for a react project which is in typescript and in all the scss files I am getting errors at import and even for variable declarations

Comment: @HarunYilmaz   And at the scss file I am getting TS instead of scss symbol at the name in vscode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filetype configuration was wrongly done in VS we need to set the right configuration it was TS before modified to SCSS now all the errors are gone